# Creating group with matching strings

Tags: string, arrays, group

I have a long list of strings. I want to automatically regroup them depending on their similitude. For example

```
Anna loves to speak to Mary
Joey like to work with Jefferson
Michael loves to speak to John when he's on the shelf
Karen hates crying at her son
```

Would give (sorted by group size)

Group 1:

```
Anna loves to speak to Mary
Michael loves to speak to John when he's on the shelf
```

Group 2:

```
Joey like to work with Jefferson
```

Group 3:

```
Karen hates crying at her son
```

I don't necessarily want precisely theses groups, as long as they're well grouped by similitude it's fine for me. As long as it detects principals patterns

Comment: This question sounds rather broad. Also, some more details are required, e.g.: How do you define "similitude"? What should happen (e.g.) when a line contains both `likes` and `hates`?

Comment: This sounds like a little programming job, where is the unix/linux connection?

Comment: What, precisely, are you trying to do?  Your question is quite vague at the moment.  Do you have a list of verbs you want to group by (e.g. loves, likes, hates, speak, work, crying)? or do you want to group by the words immediately preceding a preposition (to, at, with, etc)? The "Joey" line could match a group called "like" or a group called "work" (or both groups).    Or do you have some other unspecified grouping criteria? Can a line be in multiple groups? or only one?

Comment: @ adminbee When a line contain likes and hates and another line contain likes and hates, when they have two words in common, comparing the rest of the line can maybe lead to 100% similitude if they're identical, otherwise it will be similar between 2 words % and all words %. @ Henrik The connection is that I only know shell scripting, not programming. @ cas I have a long list of strings. Each strings is one line, on my example I grouped 4 strings. I want to group those strings, not grouping words or verbs, not depending on verbs but on similarity of characters, any of them, wether its Joey or

Comment: rgezrf. A line can't be in multiple groups

Comment: Computers aren't magic, nor can they read minds.  If you want it to put your lines into groups, you're going to have to define those groups, and the criteria for putting a line into one group but not another.  You're going to have to learn some programming.  and some kind of statistical analysis, perhaps even neural networks.  In short, you're saying "I want to group them". We're saying, "Yes, we know that.  HOW do you want to group them? What grouping rules do you have in mind?".

Comment: BTW, I wrote two variations of a simple perl script, ~ 10 lines of code. One that grouped words by defined verbs and the other by verbs in proximity to defined prepositions. They both work, in the sense that they assign the input lines into a group (or with a minor change, into one or more groups).  But neither of them are magic or smart. In both, I had to provide a list of search words (verbs in one, prepositions in the other), and in neither case did the scripts know what a verb or a noun or a preposition was. They just look for patterns. Computers do what you can **tell** them to do